# creating a date and time range df in python

Tags: python, dataframe, date, time

I would like to start from a blank. I would like to create a per minute time from the date range say,2020-12-05 to 2020-12-10. The only process I know is in excel and save it as csv but it is tedious to create per minute from 2020-12-05 to 2021-05-31. And most likely will not fit in a worksheet.

Example:

```
date       | time
---------- | -----
2020-12-05 | 00:00:00
2020-12-05 | 00:01:00
2020-12-05 | 00:02:00
2020-12-05 | 00:03:00
2020-12-05 | 00:04:00
.
.
.
2021-05-31 | 23:57:00
2021-05-31 | 23:58:00
2021-05-31 | 23:59:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `date_range` and split the date and time part.  Keep in mind the end date will be the beginning of the day, so you may want to set the end date one extra day ahead.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.date_range(start='12-05-2020',end='05-31-2021',freq='min').astype(str).str.split(' ', expand=True).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['date','time']
```